# Как преобразовать папку в файл?

Tags: c#

Есть папка. Как сделать, чтобы она выглядела в системе как файл, с каким-нибудь расширением (любым)? Чтобы этим файлом можно было работать, как с любым в системе (копировать, вставлять, удалять).

Answer (score 1):

Это папка. Файл не может быть папкой, с папкой нельзя работать, как с файлом. Папку можно только заархивировать.

Answer (score 1):

А что, не преобразовывая вы не можете копировать/вставлять/удалять папку? Преобразовывать не нужно, по факту папка это и есть файл в котором прописаны ссылки на другие файлы (в том числе и на файлы-папки т.е. подпапки)

Если это то, что вам нужно есть специальные средства, но называть их я вам не буду (RAW......) потому что неумелыми действиями в них вы можете убить всю файловую структуру - потерять данные на всем диске